# How to debug library in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

Recently I have started working on angular 6 library. So i have less knowledge of this new library feature.

I want to debug the library application when it is used inside the test application. I generally do debugging in chrome. 
When i build the library using command

> ng build lib-name

It creates the map file along with the js files in the dist folder. But when i run the test application which is using this library, i am not able to see the .ts files of the library which makes my debugging difficult as debugging in compiled js version is not easy. Please share your thoughts if you figure out how we can debug the library ts file in test application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using and why would you want to debug it ? Depending on your answers to that, this can be very simple or very difficult.

Comment: Debug while you are developing it and then go for a build.

Comment: JS library is complied version of TS files and it wont be possible to de-compile back to TS code while debugging.

Comment: @trichetriche, I am using angular 6 framework with library feature. Details you can find here. https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11

Comment: @DavidR To my understanding i need to build the library first and then use this library in the test application. Since the library is already build therefore i am not able to see the .ts file of the library while debugging the test application.

Comment: Apart from this issue. Do anybody know, Is there a way to do hot reloading in library? Which means when i change anything in library file and save it , it should reflect the screen and i don't have to run the build the library again. Please help if anyone know this.

Comment: @nikhil read through this story, than you know everything you want to know ;) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library